# Mysql query to Join two tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am writing a simple chat service. I want to pick out a messages thread between two people only a sender and a recipient using either their usernames or user ids. I have my query below. It has a slight problem, is returning a message twice. How can I fix this?

For example if my sender has the uid '101' and my recipient has the username 'janed', my query is

```
SELECT * FROM chat LEFT JOIN users ON sender=uid OR receiver=uid  WHERE username='janed' OR (sender='101' AND receiver='janed') OR (sender='janed' AND receiver='101') ORDER BY msg_id ASC
```

**Users table**

```
---------------------------------
uid |fname  |mname  |username   |
---------------------------------
101 |John   |Doe    |jdoe       |
---------------------------------
102 |Jane   |Doe    |janed      |
---------------------------------
103 |Ann    |Other  |aother     |
---------------------------------
```

**Chat table**

```
---------------------------------------------
msg_id  |sender |receiver   |content        |
---------------------------------------------
1       |101    |102        | Hello Jane    |
---------------------------------------------
2       |102    |101        | Hello John    |
---------------------------------------------
3       |103    |101        | Hi John       |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In general I think you can fix your problem with a group by. However, you should probably only query on sender/receiver, as it is a bit unwieldy to have all these OR clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    chat
        LEFT JOIN
    users ON sender = uid OR receiver = uid
WHERE
    username = 'janed'
        OR (sender = '101' AND receiver = 'janed')
        OR (sender = 'janed' AND receiver = '101')
GROUP BY msg_id
ORDER BY msg_id ASC
```

Comment: Your answer returns a row with repeated data when I use a number in place of the username

Comment: Can you post the new query?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    u.*, c.*
  FROM Users u
  LEFT JOIN Chat c ON (
    c.sender = u.uid OR c.receiver = u.uid
  )
  WHERE u.uid = 101 OR u.uid = 102 /* and/or other conditions */
  GROUP BY c.msg_id
  ORDER BY c.msg_id ASC
```

Comment: I want to select between a single user and a recepient. Your query lists all the threads in a chat. I want to select messages between two users only